# spring + Hibernate mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am new to the spring mvc and i want to do validation in spring+hibernate using mvc annotations, i have added two jars for that (hibernate-validator-5.0.1.final.jar and hibernate-validator-5.0.1.final.jar).
I am getting exception  as follow can anybody help please,
thanks in advance

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
```

Comment: It looks like the logging dependency from hibernate validator is missing. how have you added the hibernate validator dependency? Do you use maven or gradle to manage your dependencies?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springmvc/springmvc_hibernate_validator.htm check this tutorial.

Comment: Did you mean to say a different jar in this - `(hibernate-validator-5.0.1.final.jar and hibernate-validator-5.0.1.final.jar)` as jar name is repeated? Also, are you using spring boot? which app server you deploying to?